# Get the area for a specific point's corresponding region in a Voronoi diagram

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665491/getting-a-bounded-polygon-coordinates-from-voronoi-cells), I can create a bounded Voronoi diagram (credit to @Flabetvibes for this code):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.spatial
import sys

eps = sys.float_info.epsilon

def in_box(towers, bounding_box):
    return np.logical_and(np.logical_and(bounding_box[0] <= towers[:, 0],
                                         towers[:, 0] <= bounding_box[1]),
                          np.logical_and(bounding_box[2] <= towers[:, 1],
                                         towers[:, 1] <= bounding_box[3]))


def voronoi(towers, bounding_box):
    # Select towers inside the bounding box
    i = in_box(towers, bounding_box)
    # Mirror points
    points_center = towers[i, :]
    points_left = np.copy(points_center)
    points_left[:, 0] = bounding_box[0] - (points_left[:, 0] - bounding_box[0])
    points_right = np.copy(points_center)
    points_right[:, 0] = bounding_box[1] + (bounding_box[1] - points_right[:, 0])
    points_down = np.copy(points_center)
    points_down[:, 1] = bounding_box[2] - (points_down[:, 1] - bounding_box[2])
    points_up = np.copy(points_center)
    points_up[:, 1] = bounding_box[3] + (bounding_box[3] - points_up[:, 1])
    points = np.append(points_center,
                       np.append(np.append(points_left,
                                           points_right,
                                           axis=0),
                                 np.append(points_down,
                                           points_up,
                                           axis=0),
                                 axis=0),
                       axis=0)
    # Compute Voronoi
    vor = sp.spatial.Voronoi(points)
    # Filter regions
    regions = []
    for region in vor.regions:
        flag = True
        for index in region:
            if index == -1:
                flag = False
                break
            else:
                x = vor.vertices[index, 0]
                y = vor.vertices[index, 1]
                if not(bounding_box[0] - eps <= x and x <= bounding_box[1] + eps and
                       bounding_box[2] - eps <= y and y <= bounding_box[3] + eps):
                    flag = False
                    break
        if region != [] and flag:
            regions.append(region)
    vor.filtered_points = points_center
    vor.filtered_regions = regions
    return vor

def centroid_region(vertices):
    # Polygon's signed area
    A = 0
    # Centroid's x
    C_x = 0
    # Centroid's y
    C_y = 0
    for i in range(0, len(vertices) - 1):
        s = (vertices[i, 0] * vertices[i + 1, 1] - vertices[i + 1, 0] * vertices[i, 1])
        A = A + s
        C_x = C_x + (vertices[i, 0] + vertices[i + 1, 0]) * s
        C_y = C_y + (vertices[i, 1] + vertices[i + 1, 1]) * s
    A = 0.5 * A
    C_x = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_x
    C_y = (1.0 / (6.0 * A)) * C_y
    return np.array([[C_x, C_y]])

points = np.array([[0.17488374, 0.36498964],
   [0.94904866, 0.80085891],
   [0.89265224, 0.4160692 ],
   [0.17035869, 0.82769497],
   [0.30274931, 0.04572908],
   [0.40515272, 0.1445514 ],
   [0.23191921, 0.08250689],
   [0.48713553, 0.94806717],
   [0.77714412, 0.46517511],
   [0.25945989, 0.76444964]])

vor = voronoi(points,(0,1,0,1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
# Plot initial points
ax.plot(vor.filtered_points[:, 0], vor.filtered_points[:, 1], 'b.')
# Plot ridges points
for region in vor.filtered_regions:
    vertices = vor.vertices[region, :]
    ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'go')
# Plot ridges
for region in vor.filtered_regions:
    vertices = vor.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
    ax.plot(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], 'k-')
```

[image]

Now, I want to get the area of the region containing one of the original points in blue, such as points[0]. In this example, points[0] is the point (0.17488374, 0.36498964). I thought I could find the area for this point with the following code:

```
area = ConvexHull(vor.vertices[vor.filtered_regions[0], :]).volume
```

Because I figured that the index of 0 in points[0] would correspond with the index of 0 in vor.filtered_regions[0]. But it doesn't -- vor.filtered_regions[9] is actually what I'm looking for (which I figured out manually but I'd like for it to be automated). In another example, the region with index 2 was the one I was looking for, so it doesn't appear consistent either.

Is there a way to find the index for vor.filtered_regions that'll give me the area I want? Or is there another way to go about this? Even though I'm creating the entire Voronoi diagram with all 10 points, the area of the region with points[0] is all I'm actually looking for (while still being bounded), so I'm assuming there might be a quicker way to go about doing this but I have no idea what that may be.

Answer (score 2):

The [point_region](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html) attribute of the scipy Voronoi diagram tells you which region is associated to which point. So you can use that data to look up the associated regions.

Here is a much simplified version of your voronoi function which uses that attribute to ensure that filted_points and filtered_regions are constructed consistently, i.e., the first region is the one associated with the first point.

```
def voronoi(towers, bounding_box):
    # Select towers inside the bounding box
    i = in_box(towers, bounding_box)
    # Mirror points
    points_center = towers[i, :]
    points_left = np.copy(points_center)
    points_left[:, 0] = bounding_box[0] - (points_left[:, 0] - bounding_box[0])
    points_right = np.copy(points_center)
    points_right[:, 0] = bounding_box[1] + (bounding_box[1] - points_right[:, 0])
    points_down = np.copy(points_center)
    points_down[:, 1] = bounding_box[2] - (points_down[:, 1] - bounding_box[2])
    points_up = np.copy(points_center)
    points_up[:, 1] = bounding_box[3] + (bounding_box[3] - points_up[:, 1])
    points = np.append(points_center,
                       np.append(np.append(points_left,
                                           points_right,
                                           axis=0),
                                 np.append(points_down,
                                           points_up,
                                           axis=0),
                                 axis=0),
                       axis=0)
    # Compute Voronoi
    vor = sp.spatial.Voronoi(points)
    # Filter regions
    regions = []
    [vor.point_region[i] for i in range(10)]

    vor.filtered_points = points_center
    vor.filtered_regions = [vor.regions[vor.point_region[i]] for i in range(len(points_center))]
    return vor
```